# How to do connect to ubuntu machine (remote desktop) from windows machine remotely?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, remote-desktop, user-accounts

How to do connect to Ubuntu machine (remote desktop) from windows machine remotely? I need to add an account on my Ubuntu machine. Maybe through ssh?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [vnc viewer](http://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/) for remote desktop activities like in windows and for accessing Linux machine through SSH  try [PuTTy](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). Read this [howto](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/remote-windows-linux.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SSH, there's a tool called [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) that is widely used.

Simply download the program, specify the address, and then it will prompt you to log in. Keep in mind, this is command-line only. If you want remote desktop access, you might need something along the lines of Teamviewer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use teamviewer.. It's windows/linux/mac OS compatible.
www.teamviewer.com